# Would like to take a Perl variable and pass it to bash

Tags: perl, variables, unix, storage

I am trying to enter storage commands like symmask in Unix. I would like to build a script that would take a variable from Perl like standard input and then use that variable in a bash shell. I have been trying to do both in Perl but I can't run the storage command in Perl script. Unless I am just missing it.

Comment: Why do you think you *can't* run the storage command from a Perl script ?

Comment: Perl: ``$text =  `command arg1 arg2`;``

Comment: when I added my storage command it would just look at me funny. Like you want me to do something. I could get it to print but i couldnt get it to execute. I can get my script to run the command in bash but not perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can run all external programs and commands from Perl with `system`, `exec` and the backtick-operator (``` `` ``` and `qx()`).

Please refer to:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html

If you want to, say, copy stuff to another server, you can use the backticks like this:

```
my $file = 'foo.csv';
`scp foo.csv someone@otherserver:dir/foo.csv`;
```